# php functions not working

Tags: php, function, exec

I am trying to get these functions to work. When I issue `KillEsniper` I tend to get empty results, and nothing happens. I have stared at this code for days now and it does not work and I cant seem to see whats wrong with it. A pair of second eyes would probably do miracles.

```
    function KillEsniper($pid) {
        if (isEsniperRunning($pid) == true) {
            exec("kill -15 ".$pid);
            putEsniperLog("-KILLESNIPER- Killing esniper process with pid {$pid}");
        }
    }

    function getPids() {
        $output = shell_exec("pidof -x esniper");
        if ($output != "\n") {
            $pids = split(" ",rtrim($output));
        }
        return($pids);
    }

    function isEsniperRunning($pid) {
        $pids = getPids();
        if (!empty($pids)) {
            if (strpos($pid,$pids)) {
                return(true);
            }
        } else {
            return(false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: *sidenote:* no need `()` in `return` line. Plus, the function `KillEsniper` does not return anything. What is  your expected result?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor Its the killEsniper function that doesn't kill the pid. even tho i know its running.

Comment: have you ever tried to debug `$output` or `$pids` with `var_dump()` ?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor The results are for var_dump: NULL output: array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } pids: Array

Comment: since `$output` is null, how can the process be killed?

Comment: $output = shell_exec("/sbin/pidof -x esniper 2>&1"); solved the issue. Took a while to figure it out. I do need to be better at taking breaks before i turn blind :P

Answer (score 0):

getPids returns an array into $pids. You're trying to search in it then with strpos. Either don't split it or search it as an array...

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
function getPids() 
{
    $output = shell_exec("pidof -x esniper");
    $pids = array();
    if ($output != "\n") {
        $pids = split(" ",rtrim($output));
    }
    return $pids;
}

function isEsniperRunning($pid) {
    $pids = getPids();
    if (count($pids)) 
    {
        if (in_array($pid,$pids)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```